# Connect docker container to VPN

Tags: maven, docker, ubuntu-14.04, vpn, ubuntu-16.04

I have a docker container from which I build and package a Java application with maven 3. I have some dependencies deployed to a Nexus server, I can only access through a VPN from local. How can I connect my docker container to that VPN?

**docker image details:**

> **Base image** : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as base system
>
> Java 8, maven 3, Tomcat 8 installed
>
> To create my docker container (I didn't add any network configuration):
>
> ```
> docker run -it --rm -v '$PWD':/app -w /app/app-parent appImage/v:02 mvn clean install
> ```
>
> **And that's the error i get:**
>
> ```
> INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to {}->http://myserver:80: No route to host (Host unreachable)
> ```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "can only access through a VPN from local"? Is your docker host connected to VPN? Or your workstation/laptop is connected to VPN and docker host is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is due to DNS only.

Try resolving nexus hostname in the container's `/etc/hosts` file (or change maven `settings.xml` so that  tag of nexus repository looks for the ip instead of the hostname).

To check if that is the problem, simply connect to the container

```
docker exec -ti yourContainer /bin/bash
```

then try to contact the host (depending on what you installed on the container, you could use ping, wget or other) with hostaname and ip address.