# How can Docker containers access servers behind a VPN?

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, vpn

My usecase seems pretty simple:
- use jenkins/jenkins image locally (or on a server outside of a VPN, does not matter)
- checkout a git repo from a private repository (repository is inside a VPN)

I can do that without any issues on my Ubuntu machine, but I get `Name or service not known` when doing the same on a docker powered Jenkins.

Same thing happens if I do that with an explicit IP address, which I guess means that it's not a DNS issue.

I've seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904647/docker-container-and-host-network-vpn) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483231/connect-docker-container-to-vpn), but either I can't understand something or there is something different being solved there.

I do *not* want to use a different image (like openvpn image or something), because I'd have to do that for every little thing that I want to run through docker (so java-based images, databases and whatnot) some time in future, which means I'd have to create and manage my own images, which seems pointless.

I'd like to use docker-compose to set my docker image up properly for that purpose.

So... any tips for me? :)

---

edit: just to focus your attention - my docker-compose looks like this:

`my-jenkins:
  image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
  ports:
    - "9091:8080"
    - "50000:50000"
  volumes:
    - jenkins_home:/tmp/jenkins`